# Binding a label to an object property

Tags: object, binding, actionscript, mxml

I am doing an intro to as project where I have a class, Einstein, that has a property of name. The name property is private, but I have getters and setters for it. In the mxml file, I have a label and a button. The label displays the Einstein object's name. When the button is clicked, the name of the Einstein object is changed. Since the label is binded to the name property, it should update but it is not. Below is the portions of the Einstein as file and the mxml file that could possibly have anything to do with the problem.

```
    [Bindable]
public class Einstein
{
    private var name:String;

    public function Einstein(name:String)
    {setName(name);}

    public function getName():String
    {return name;}

    public function setName(sentName:String):void
    {this.name = sentName;}
}
```

---

```
        <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        var pEinstein: Einstein = new Einstein("Brighid");
    ]]>

        <s:Label id="nameTag" text="{pEinstein.getName()}" fontSize="24"/>
        <s:Button content="change the name">
            <s:click>
                pEinstein.setName("Freyja");
            </s:click>
```

tldr; my label isn't updating when it is supposed to

Answer (score 0):

I usualy do not work in flex, but try this:
(actual getter/setter AS3 syntax)

```
public class Einstein
{
private var _name:String;

public function Einstein(name:String)
{setName(name);}

public function get name():String
{return _name;}

public function set name(value:String):void
{_name = value;}
}
```

and

```
<![CDATA[
    [Bindable]
    var pEinstein: Einstein = new Einstein("Brighid");
]]>

    <s:Label id="nameTag" text="{pEinstein.name}" fontSize="24"/>
    <s:Button content="change the name">
        <s:click>
            pEinstein.setName("Freyja");
        </s:click>
```

Answer (score -1):

Automatic binding does not work for 'normal' methods. It does for getters/setters, but you'll need to use actionscript syntax for getters and setters. (your get/set functions look like the syntax as I'd use in java - this does work in actionscript, but they won't be recognized as get/set by the mxml compiler)

Change your get/set functions to this:

```
public function get name():String
{return name;}

public function set name(sentName:String):void
{this.name = sentName;}
```

Change your call in the click handler to:

```
pEinstein.name = "Freyja";
```

And change the label to:

```
<s:Label id="nameTag" text="{pEinstein.name}" fontSize="24"/>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! Works perfectly!

As a sidenote to anyone else that uses this solution, the getter/setter name cannot be the same as the name of the variable

Comment: If this solution works for you please mark the answer as 'accepted' by checking the green mark next to it. This way others will know the question has been answered.